# Opening folder with .gl extension in python or pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I downloaded some data from an online course I'm following.

Once unzipped it generates a folder called home.gl (the folder comes with that gl extension) and inside that folder they are these strange extension files. In the course they use graphlab (paid programm) but they say one can use Pandas too.

This is data that can be loaded into a DataFrame and they actually just load it doing:

```
sales = graphlab.SFrame('home_data.gl/')
```

This is the image of what got extracted.
[image]

How can I load this data into Python, preferably pandas?

These are their instructions.

[image]

Comment: which file has the data?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham I don't know, I'm guessing is the one that ends with .0000 just because of the size, but couldn't figure out how to open a .0000 extension file. It looks like they just open the "whole folder" when they upload to sframes.

Comment: can you upload the files somewhere?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham just added a dropbox link. thanks.

Comment: This looks like a compound file type - probably because it's a database. You are not supposed to manually unzip it; the original software 'knows' where to look. Perhaps [converting it to csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) is easier than parsing the binary file format.

Comment: @Jongware When trying to convert into csv i got the following error:

TypeError: unbound method to_csv() must be called with DataFrame instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Comment: @Gabriel, do they not supply the data in any raw format?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham , no unfortunately they don't. I guess will try to request the raw data. (Just uploaded a pic of their instructions on how to download in case it helps).

Comment: @Gabriel, what is the course name?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham, Machine Learning Foundations: A Case Study Approach

Comment: @Gabriel, you know you can install graphlab for free for the course including a python  api?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham, yeah but its a 1 year license and I plan to use ML for work longer than that. Now actually someone in a post just linked the raw data. So I downloaded that. Still wondering how to open this data without graphlabs though. Thank you very much for your help.Voting one of your comments.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted

Comment: Use turicreate and then save to csv.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can always save SFrame to csv and create pandas DataFrame from csv:

```
sf = sframe.SFrame('Downloads/home_data.gl/') 
sf.save('Downloads/home_data.csv', format='csv')
df = pandas.read_csv('Downloads/home_data.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer as of 2018/05, [turicreate](https://github.com/apple/turicreate)

Run `pip install turicreate`. And then

```
In [1]: import turicreate as tc

In [2]: data = tc.SFrame('./case_study_approach/week2/home_data.gl/')

In [4]: data.save('./case_study_approach/week2/home_data.csv', format='csv')

In [5]: !less ./case_study_approach/week2/home_data.csv
```

This package supports many platform well. Instructions are better and cleaner for installation. SFrame is simply deprecated and cannot be installed on Linux.

Comment: Are you using the ! as part of a shebang?

Answer (score 0):

See your point... Taking the same course and wanted to know how to do it also. My findings:  The SFrame Package is licensed under a BSD license :)

Here is what I did:

```
pip install -U sframe
```

Then in ipython notebook:

```
import sframe

people = sframe.SFrame('people_wiki.gl/')
```

It worked.

Comment: Please post your question as a comment to OP, not in answer

Answer (score 0):

At this time I tried to import sframe but I got following error:

> No module named 'sframe'

I tried to install `sframe` with following:

```
pip install -U sframe
```

And you can't use `conda` to install the `sframe` on Linux or Windows, except on Mac devices.

long story short I got different errors.

I'm here to say, since this dataset is from either `graphlab create` or `SFrame` you can use following code using `graphlab create`:

```
import graphlab

sf = graphlab.SFrame('home_data.gl/')
sf.save('home_data.csv' , format = 'csv')
```

And for those who have access to `Online iPython Notebook`, no need to install the `ghraphlab create`. Just use it as it is and you'll get the `home_data.csv` dataset in your notebook.

Answer (score 0):

if you are taking the Coursera course, either enrolled or auditing - they have provided link to get grapghlab create with free student license valid for a year. And if you dont want to store it locally, you can avail the aws hosted free tier.