# Pandas: How to open certain files

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working on the data set from this [link](https://github.com/smarthi/UnivOfWashington-Machine-Learning/tree/master/MLFoundations/week4/people_wiki.gl). But I am unable to read these files from Pandas? Has anyone tried to play with such files?

I am trying the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("m_4549381c276b46c6.0000")
```

But I get the following error

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.
```

Comment: can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: Thanks. Please have a look at the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those files are parts of a saved [SFrame](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.html).

So you can load them this way:

```
import sframe

sf = sframe.SFrame('/path/to/dir/')
```

Demo: I've downloaded all files from [people_wiki.gl](https://github.com/smarthi/UnivOfWashington-Machine-Learning/tree/master/MLFoundations/week4/people_wiki.gl) and put them under: `D:/download/sframe/`

```
In [7]: import sframe

In [7]: sf = sframe.SFrame('D:/download/sframe/')

In [8]: sf
Out[8]:
Columns:
        URI     str
        name    str
        text    str

Rows: 59071

Data:
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
|              URI              |         name        |
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
| <http://dbpedia.org/resour... |    Digby Morrell    |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resour... |    Alfred J. Lewy   |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resour... |    Harpdog Brown    |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resour... | Franz Rottensteiner |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resour... |        G-Enka       |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resour... |    Sam Henderson    |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resour... |    Aaron LaCrate    |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resour... |   Trevor Ferguson   |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resour... |     Grant Nelson    |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resour... |     Cathy Caruth    |
+-------------------------------+---------------------+
+-------------------------------+
|              text             |
+-------------------------------+
| digby morrell born 10 octo... |
| alfred j lewy aka sandy le... |
| harpdog brown is a singer ... |
| franz rottensteiner born i... |
| henry krvits born 30 decem... |
| sam henderson born october... |
| aaron lacrate is an americ... |
| trevor ferguson aka john f... |
| grant nelson born 27 april... |
| cathy caruth born 1955 is ... |
+-------------------------------+
[59071 rows x 3 columns]
Note: Only the head of the SFrame is printed.
You can use print_rows(num_rows=m, num_columns=n) to print more rows and columns.
```

Now you can convert it to Pandas DF if you need:

```
In [17]: df = sf.to_dataframe()

In [18]: pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 40

In [19]: df.head()
Out[19]:
                                       URI                 name                                     text
0  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Digby_M...        Digby Morrell  digby morrell born 10 october 1979 i...
1  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Alfred_...       Alfred J. Lewy  alfred j lewy aka sandy lewy graduat...
2  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harpdog...        Harpdog Brown  harpdog brown is a singer and harmon...
3  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Franz_R...  Franz Rottensteiner  franz rottensteiner born in waidmann...
4     <http://dbpedia.org/resource/G-Enka>               G-Enka  henry krvits born 30 december 1974 i...

In [20]: df.shape
Out[20]: (59071, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you and as @Ujjawal said, I should have looked the iPython notebook. But graphlab is not free. In that case, how should we do it?

Comment: @chintans, you can simply install sframe (`pip install sframe`) as i did...

Comment: Thanks @MaxU , this helped.

Answer (score 2):

Just clarifying on the answer by [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39686244/6842947), you are trying to read it the wrong way. It is a raw file and its formatting is contained in the other files which are there in the same folder in that [link](https://github.com/smarthi/UnivOfWashington-Machine-Learning/tree/master/MLFoundations/week4/people_wiki.gl). Pandas requires you to know the encoded format of the file beforehand (i.e delimiters, number of columns etc). It cannot be used as a magic wand to read any file without being aware of it.

The IPython notebook just outside the folder in your [link](https://github.com/smarthi/UnivOfWashington-Machine-Learning/tree/master/MLFoundations/week4/people_wiki.gl), shows exactly how to read that data. [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39686244/6842947) has correctly mentioned that the specific file in question is just a part of the SFrame which is a structure of GraphLab framework. Hence, you are trying to extract meaningful data just from a part of the whole and hence you can't do that meaningfully.

You can however read the graphlab file and convert it into a Pandas dataframe. For details see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461953/opening-folder-with-gl-extension-in-python-or-pandas).

Comment: Thanks Ujjawal. I should have looked the iPython notebook. But graphlab is not free. In that case, how should we do it?

Comment: sframe constains an open source implementation of GraphLab components. You may use that. MaxU has given you an example for that. You can install sframe by pip install sframe.